# Query on clang Code Coverage and gcov version

Tags: linux, gcc, clang, gcov, lcov

I am doing gcov processing of code compiled using clang. But my report is getting generated using gcov4.6. And the developer told me GNU on FreeBSD stopped around 2012 when they upgraded their license to GPLv3. So how is it using gcov4.6 and not latest with freebsd 11.4.
I tried llvm-cov, but the generation keeps getting stuck and works perfectly with gcov4.6 tool.

Answer (score 0):

The llvm-cov gcov tool reads code coverage data files and displays the coverage information for a specified source file. It is compatible with the gcov tool from version 4.2 of GCC and may also be compatible with some later versions of gcov.

This can be the reason why it is working with older version of gcov.

https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cov.html

Comment: Nice verbatim copy/paste.